# Convert C# from full framework to core with WebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I’m not overly awesome with my `C#` but was hoping if someone could help me with my code snippet here.
First one works fine in `C#` full .net framework, the second one is where I tried to change the first over to `dotnet` core (standard 1.3), but it just doesn’t work and seems to barf out on “using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())” with “"errorMessage": "The remote server returned an `error: (400)` Bad Request.", but no idea why.
I assume it has something to do with the *async calls, but really not sure.

Thanks already and help is much appreciated.

```
public static string AcquireTokenBySpn(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            var payload = String.Format(SpnPayload, WebUtility.UrlEncode(ArmResource), WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientId),
                WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);

            var address = String.Format(TokenEndpoint, tenantId);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address);
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            string responseContent = null;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                        using (StreamReader sr99 = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            responseContent = sr99.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                }
            }

            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(responseContent);

            return (string)jObject["access_token"];
        }
```

This is the "**core snippet**".

```
    public static async Task<string> AcquireTokenBySpn(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, double apiVersion)
    {
      var payload = String.Format(SpnPayload, WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientId),
        WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));

      var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);

      var address = String.Format(TokenEndpoint, tenantId, apiVersion);

      WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address);

      request.Method = "POST";
      request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      //request. ContentLength = data.Length;
      using (Stream stream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
      {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
      }

      string responseContent = null;

      using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
      {
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
          if (stream != null)
            using (StreamReader sr99 = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
              responseContent = sr99.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
      }

      JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(responseContent);

      return (string)jObject["access_token"];
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you checked if the url and the body of the request are correct? I notice that the codes of  `payload` and  `address` are not same.

Answer (score 0):

The error sure is related to to `GetResponseAsync()`. You need to check what is happening over there. 
BTW. it is much better to work with .NETCore 2.0  rather than 1.3 as it has a vere huger library support as it supports .NET Standard 2.0 libraries.

Comment: I'm running this inside of AWS Lambda which IIRC doesn't support 2.0 yet.

Comment: You  can select the platform you run in AWS serverless function. I did not see such an option in Azure function for sure.